# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::intersect()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to make Laravel Authorization using gate..Where In user model

User.php

```
 public function hasPermission($name)
    {
       $permission = Permission::where('name','=', $name)->first();
        $permissions = \DB::table('role_permission')
            ->join('permissions', 'permissions.id', '=', 'role_permission.permission_id')
            ->select('role_permission.*')
            ->where('role_permission.permission_id', '=',$permission->id)
            ->get();  

        if(! $permissions) {
            return false;
        }

        return !! $permission->intersect($this->$permission)->count();

    }
```

In AuthserviceProvider

```
 public function boot(GateContract $gate)
        {
            $this->registerPolicies($gate);

            $gate->before(function($user, $ability) {

                  return $user->hasPermission($ability);
            });

        }
```

My Table structure like.

User has name,email,password,id
permission has name,id
role has name,id
role_permission has role_id,permission_id

can anyone help me to find out what's the error here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's because you can apply `intersect` to a **collection**, while you're getting an error saying you that you're calling it over `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`.

I see you're calling it on `$permission`, that's currently a record (a **model**) of `Permission`. Probably that's just a typo, and you want to use `$permissions` instead of `$permission`.

Anyway, try to explain better what's the behaviour you're looking for, because it's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

[`intersect`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-intersect) method belongs to `Collection` class. You can't use **intersect** method on `Model`. You may try by:

```
return !! collect([$permission])->intersect($this->$permission)->count();
```

> $this->$permission should be an `array` or `collection`